# Update field within nested array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update the subdocument within the array without success. The new data doesn't get saved.

Express:

```
router.put('/:id/:bookid', (req, res) => {
  library.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": req.params.id, "books._id": req.params.bookid},
    { 
     "$set": {
        "title.$": 'new title'
      }
    }
});
```

LibraryScema:

```
const LibarySchema = new Library({
  Name: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  }, 
  books: [BookSchema]
});
```

bookScema:

```
const BookSchema = new Schema({

  title: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  Chapters: [
    {
      chapterTitle: {
        type: String,
        required: false
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

I only aim to update the sub-document, not parent- and sub-document at same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I believe there is something wrong with the `$set` when it comes to nested arrays (There was an entire issue thread on GitHub). This is how I solved my issue.

```
var p = req.params;
var b = req.body;

Account.findById(req.user._id, function (err, acc) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        acc.websites.set(req.params._id, req.body.url); //This solved it for me
        acc.save((err, webs) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('all good');
                res.redirect('/websites');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have a user with a nested array.

Try this code

```
router.put('/:id/:bookid', (req, res) => {
    library.findById(
        req.params.id, (err, obj) => {
            if (err) console.log(err); // Debugging
            obj.books.set(req.params.bookid, {
                "title": 'new title',
                'Chapters': 'your chapters array'
            });
            obj.save((err,obj)=>{
                if(err) console.log(err); // Debugging
                else {
                    console.log(obj); // See if the saved object is what expected;
                    res.redirect('...') // Do smth here
                }
            })
        })
});
```

Let me know if it works, and I'll add explanation.

Explanation: You start by finding the right object (`library` in this case), then you find the correct object in the array called `books`.

Using `.set` you set the whole object to the new state. You'll need to take the data that's not changing from a previous instance of the library object.

I believe this way will overwrite and ***remove*** any data that's not passed into the `.set()` method. And then you `save()` the changed.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your solution as I'm new to express/mongoose. Any chance you could edit the solution so it work with my case?